# How to override Login logic in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

In the past, I used to create a custom MembershipProvider to communicate with a custom database or logic, like this:

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.EmailAddress, model.Password))
{
    (...) // validation logic
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.EmailAddress, false);
}
```

And it authenticated my user, I mean: the username is displayed in top right corner, user can access to [Authorize] controller methods, etc.

When I try this approach in MVC 5, nothing happens and it behaves like user is not authenticated.

How could I override the authentication logic in ASP.NET MVC 5?

I would like to call a Web API, service, etc. to validate my credentials and get my user authenticated having the  mentioned behaviour (the username is displayed in top right corner, user can access to [Authorize] controller methods, etc) .

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but don't you want to simply use Asp.NET Identity (http://www.asp.net/identity)?  This is included I believe by default in the MVC 5 project template.  What about it specifically do you need to customise?

Comment: I don't want to use the database. I need to connect against a remote service to authenticate.

Comment: As in an OAuth endpoint?

Comment: I am confused.  You have a web application and webapi application that are both hosted separately.  You want to authenticate against the webapi, and have that authentication valid in the web application.  You will be doing this against some form of membership provider hosted in the webapi.  Correct?

Comment: In the AccountController.cs , there is the method Login which uses SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsyn call .

I know I need to use an HttpClient to call the Web API "/Token" url to get the bearer token to be used, when getting API resources, and that this token can be stored in a cookie. How I replace this in Web App to call Web API?

Comment: You're not understanding my question. At Web API side I don't have any doubt. What I want to do is authenticate a user in my web app MVC 5. It uses a default database, I want to change the logic to connect to database and instead have a custom logic. Let's suppose my logic simply returns "true" to validate user exists. How do you that?

Comment: Check the 4-part series by the same author starting here: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Answer (score 0):

To have your own AuthZ you need to map the AuthorizeAttribute to your own customer Authorization Attribute.
You can achieve that using unity like this:

```
<alias alias="AuthorizeAttribute" type="System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute, System.Web.Http" />
<alias alias="CustomAuthorizationAttribute" type="CustomSecurity.CustomAuthorizationAttribute, CustomSecurity" />

<register type="AuthorizeAttribute" mapTo="CustomAuthorizationAttribute" />
```

Now when anyone tries to call the controller actions that has the [Authorize] attribute on them, your CustomAuthorizationAttribute class will get called.

You can take a look at this page for your reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707357(v=vs.91).aspx

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to have a customAtribute, I want my app authenticates user as I explain above.